# ClistCtrl set color of an item

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, visual-c++-2008, clistctrl

I have ClistView control in my MFC application. I need to color some of the items according to its content. For example, if it begins with "No Response to", i need to make it red.

So far, i've tried

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMessageView, CListView)
ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(NM_CUSTOMDRAW,customDraw)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CMessageView::Update()
{
CListCtrl& refCtrl = GetListCtrl();   
refCtrl.InsertItem(LVIF_TEXT|LVIF_PARAM,0,CTime::GetCurrentTime().Format("%H:%M:%S"),0,0,0,42);
refCtrl.SetItemText(0,1,"some text");
refCtrl.SetItemText(0,2,"No response to open");
}

void CMessageView::customDraw(NMHDR * pNMHDR, LRESULT * pResult)
{
_ASSERTE(*pResult == 0);

NMLVCUSTOMDRAW * pnmlvcd = (NMLVCUSTOMDRAW *)pNMHDR;

DWORD dwDrawStage = pnmlvcd->nmcd.dwDrawStage;

BOOL bSubItem = dwDrawStage & CDDS_SUBITEM;
dwDrawStage &= ~CDDS_SUBITEM;

switch (dwDrawStage)
{
case CDDS_PREPAINT:
    {
        *pResult = CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
        break;
    }
case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
case CDDS_SUBITEM:
    {
            if(pnmlvcd->nmcd.lItemlParam == 42)
            {
                pnmlvcd->clrText = RGB(255,0,0);            

            }               
            *pResult = 0;               
        break;
    }
default:
    {
        *pResult = 0;
        break;
    }
}
}
```

But it does not work. The color does not change. Am i missing something or doing something wrong?

Comment: I've done this with great success in the past, but my MFC days are long behind me.  Try reading this and giving your handler similar code:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79/Neat-Stuff-to-Do-in-List-Controls-Using-Custom-Dra

Comment: This is way easier to do do with a CMFCListCtrl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code in a simple example application worked for me.  My list control has two columns and two items.  The second item, second column has item data set to 42, in this case, only that particular subitem had the text changed to red.

```
void CMFCTestDlg::OnNMCustomdrawList1(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
   NMLVCUSTOMDRAW* pLVCD = reinterpret_cast<NMLVCUSTOMDRAW*>( pNMHDR );
   // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here

   *pResult = CDRF_DODEFAULT;

   switch(pLVCD->nmcd.dwDrawStage)
   {
   case CDDS_PREPAINT:
      *pResult = CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
      break;

   case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
      *pResult = CDRF_NOTIFYSUBITEMDRAW;
      break;

   case (CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT | CDDS_SUBITEM):
      {
         if(1 == pLVCD->iSubItem)
         {
            if(pLVCD->nmcd.lItemlParam == 42)
            {
               pLVCD->clrText = RGB(255, 0, 0);
            }
         }
      }
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: while debugging, my code only goes far as CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT block. it never goes to (CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT | CDDS_SUBITEM) block. When i put pLVCD->clrText = RGB(255, 0, 0); into CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT block, nothing happens. Also, when i use SetTextColor(RGB(255,255,255)) to make all of the entries red, it stays black.

Answer (score 3):

If you have VS2008 SP1, it's much easier to use [`CMFCListCtrl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983191.aspx) instead - it has virtual functions you can override to set the foreground and background colours of each row.